# Health Tests on NVMe

Tags: centos, smart, healthcheck, smartctl, nvme

On the servers I have, with HDD or SSD, I have a cron that periodically runs:

```
/usr/sbin/smartctl --test=short/long /dev/sd1
```

(for each disk)

While it runs, it just looks at the output of `/usr/sbin/smartctl -c /dev/sd1`,
looping until it no longer contains:

```
[0-9]+% of test remaining.
```

And then checks if it completed without errors:

```
(   0)  The previous self-test routine completed
```

However, it appears that `smartctl` doesn't yet support testing of NVMe, as of version 7.0, and as per: https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/NVMe_Support

It does say that

> The smartd daemon tracks health (-H), error count (-l error) and temperature (-W DIFF,INFO,CRIT)

but what does actually run the tests?
I'm not sure if the output of `-H` and `-l` update unless we run short/long tests?

I also read about `nvme-cli`, but I don't seem to find ways of running health tests on disks with it.

Any ideas?

Using CentOS 7 here.

Comment: I don't *know*, but I would be surprised if running any explicit test would have a very large knowledge advantage for SSDs – these things are in a perfect position to track their own health, since wear leveling literally knows how often each memory segment has been used, *and* due to the comprehensive error-correction code inherent to NVMe devices, you get a very good picture of device aging simply from day-to-day usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMART self-test were conceived for mechanical disks. SATA SSDs almost completely mirrors earlier HDD interface-level behavior supporting such self-test but not doing very much when you run it, actually. NVMe drives dropped such SMART self-test routines entirely.

For flash-based disks one should really track cells wear, spare block count and reallocated sectors rather then relying on old self-test routines which are not supported on NVMe drives.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes sense. Do you know if I just leave `smartd` running, will it let me know of any NVMe disk problems though syslog messages? All I want is to rest assured that I'm covered, and not negligent :-)

Comment: As far I know, `smartd` should be capable of monitoring NVMe SSD health as well to alert in case the drive itself reports a non-healthy status.

Answer (score 3):

Get the NVME test client installed

```
sudo apt install nvme-cli
```

Find the drive you want to check

```
nvme list
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1
```

There are some other self-test commands you can run with this command too, I believe these give the old short/long tests that smartctl did.

```
nvme device-self-test /dev/nvme0 -n 1 -s 1
nvme self-test-log /dev/nvme0n1
```